# How can you solve $y_t=Dy_{xx}+1$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose we have $y=y(x,t)$ defined on $x\in [0,L] $ where

$$y_t=Dy_{xx}+1$$

And on $x=0,L$ respectively we have
$$-Dy_x=a(y-y_0)$$
$$-Dy_x=b(y-y_L)$$

How can this be solved? Ideally with a fourier transform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In problems of the form $Tu=Lu+F(t,x)$ where $T$ is a linear temporal differential operator and $L$ is a linear spatial differential operator, a good place to start is to solve $Tv=Lv$ in general and $Tw=F(t,x)$, $Lw=0$ in general. Then try to solve your problem with initial and boundary conditions with $u=v+w$, for appropriately chosen $v,w$. This works out because linear equations obey a superposition principle, so that

$$Tu=Tv+Tw=Lv+F(t,x)=Lv+0+F(t,x)=Lu+F(t,x).$$

Then hopefully you can solve the two subproblems and choose $v,w$ to match your initial and boundary conditions.

In this problem it looks like these both work out: you find the general solution to the diffusion equation on the interval (with no boundary conditions yet), then you add $ax+b+t$ to that, then you choose $a,b$ and the Fourier coefficients to match the initial conditions and the boundary conditions.